# Correct size solar panel to directly run a PC fan?

Tags: power

I'm a novice wanting to put together a solar powered fan to help ventilate a house in sunny Spain.  I have a Pengda technology 'electricity 0.15 A' (is the term it uses) 12v 80mm computer fan. I tried this on a 12 volt car battery and it worked fine. I then tried it on a solar car battery charger 1.5A   17.5volts in the midday sun - nothing. What size of solar panel do I need, please. I only need it to operate when the sun is shining and without batteries.  Many thanks

Comment: Your solar panel could be protected and not do anything until it's connected to a battery... or it could just be lying massively about its specs as most of them usually are.

Comment: Any suggestions as to what alternative solar panel I might need?

Comment: Not really, you need to discover what the deal is with your existing one because a ~25W panel should really have no problem running a PC fan, although you may want a small regulator to keep it to 12v so it doesn't burn the fan out.

Comment: John, That's been really helpful, thank you.  Regards Derek

Comment: John, Just another supplementary question please.  So (in broad terms), if I limit the current of the solar panel to 12 volts I won't be able to burn out the fan even if the wattage of the panel is much higher than that of the requirements of the fan. Regards Derek

Comment: Yes, very basically devices *draw* current, but volts *push* the current, so too many volts is bad (breaks things) but as long as the supply voltage is correct the device doesn't care if the supply *could* provide 1A, 10A or 100A it will only draw what it needs. However, often a fuse is a good idea as you don't want a fault leading to 100A making its way through a device that's designed to draw 1A.

Comment: John,Thanks once again for your help. I now think understand the basics of what I need